# Flask Restful: Converting CSV file to JSON Object

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask, flask-restful

I'm reading a file from the frontend and converting it to JSON consists of uuid and a list of JSON objects:

```
class File(Resource):

def post(self):
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return {"message": "No File in the request!"}, 400
    file = request.files['file']

    if file.filename == '':
        return {'message': "No File selected!"}, 400

    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

    #file_contents = file.read()
    print(file)
    converted_json = File.csv2json(file)
    new_request = {
            'uuid': str(uuid.uuid4()),
            'devices': converted_json
        }
    print(new_request)
    return new_request, 201

@classmethod
def csv_to_json(cls, data):
    df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None)
    df.columns = ['name', 'username', 'password', 'domain']
    print(df)
    df = df.to_json(orient='records')
    print(df)
    return df
```

Output is double encoded:
{
    "uuid": "1a09ad79-dc78-4759-9aa0-f1dda9c08dc4",
    "details": "[{\"name\":\"joe\",\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"admin\",\"domain\":\"abc.xyz.com\"}]"
}

How to get JSON Object output like (with newline at the end of each ','):

```
{
"uuid": "1a09ad79-dc78-4759-9aa0-f1dda9c08dc4",
"details": [
               {"name": "joe",
                "username": "admin",
                "password": "admin",
                "domain"" "abc.xyz.com"}
           ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind!

Using 'json.loads(df)' after 'df = df.to_json(orient='records')' did the trick!